# No active compatible AVD's or devices found when DDMS shows my device

Tags: android, adb

I am using Samsung Galaxy S2 with Gingerbread
I can run other programs in my android workspace just fine, but when I imported this particular project (which I had previously made to run on an Asus Nexus 7 on a different computer), the phone shows up on DDMS, but I get the error shown when I try to run my project (for this particular project only, whne I run the program the device sellection dialog box doesn't show anything, and if I set the project to run on all active devices then I get this error in the logcat)
How do I get my project to detect my phone?

Comment: Check the minSdkVersion of the project.

Comment: I'm sorry I am not very experienced with Android yet could you please tell me how to see this value?

Comment: ok Sorry I saw it in manifest. It is android:minSdkVersion="14"

Comment: Changing this to 8 as in the other running project gets the program to start running. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, just be careful as it might've been set that way because it uses APIs that are only present in that platform. But it depends on the project, of course. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am afraid you were probably right as the program runs, but soon crashes and the logcat shows that one of the display related functions is not present, while the IDE dos not show any error at the line where the display function is used